# Filter by date in Java with startDate and endDate

Tags: java, date

In database I have

```
eventName: "TestEvent",
startDate : ISODate("2018-11-07T13:24:03.124Z"),
endDate: ISODate("2020-11-07T13:24:03.124Z")
```

I am setting two dates `fromDate` and `toDate`,
for example

```
fromDate:01/01/2020
toDate:01/01/2021
```

I want to check if the event is within this range I entered.
I tried like this but the results are not correct.

```
if ((fromDate.after(s.getStartDate()) && toDate.before(s.getEndDate()))
|| s.getStartDate().equals(fromDate) || s.getEndDate().equals(toDate))
```

Please help me, I am using utils.Date in my project.

If i use :

```
fromDate:08/08/2017
toDate: 09/09/2022
```

or

```
fromDate:08/08/2019
toDate: 09/09/2019
```

it should return this event in this range.

If i use :

```
fromDate:01/01/2000
toDate: 01/01/2001
```

this event should not be in the results

Comment: **Don't use `java.util.Date`**, instead **use `java.time.OffsetDateTime` or `java.time.ZonedDateTime` or `java.time.LocalDate`**... And for the check, find their methods `isBefore()` and `isAfter()`.

Comment: On top of deHaar said, are you sure your conditions are correct? Like shouldn't `fromDate.after(s.getStartDate())` be changed to `fromDate.before(s.getStartDate())` and same for the second?

Comment: if startDate is 07/11/2018, valid fromDates are all dates after this date or equal to it, 08/11;09/12; etc. 
so, if i enter 09/09/2019-09/09/2020 it should return this event in that range @Amongalen

Comment: i updated my question, i hope is more clear now what I am looking for

Comment: Do you require your event to be *completely within* the range from `fromDate` to `toDate`, or is it enough that it overlaps (some of the time falls within the range)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to check whether two (time) intervals overlap. A simple way to look at it is to say that overlap occurs if (and only if) one or more of the start and end of the 1st interval is within the 2nd, **or vice-versa**. Test it with:

```
boolean contains(Date d, Date startInclusive, Date endExclusive) {
     return d.compareTo(startInclusive) >= 0 && d.before(endExclusive);
}
```

yielding

```
boolean intersects(Date from, Date to, Date start, Date end) {
     return contains(from, start, end) || // s <= f < e (from inside start-end)
            contains(to, start, end) ||   // s <= t < e (to inside start-end)
            contains(start, from, to);    // f <= s < t (from-to fully contains start-end)
}
```

Note that this is much more readable than writing the (equivalent) boolean expression.

I also fully agree with @deHaar's comment: *use classes in java.time instead of java.util.Date*. There are many problems with java.util.Date, which is deprecated as of Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you compare the dates they are in the same format.

I think there is an issue with condition and it should look more like :

```java
Date startDate = s.getStartDate();
Date endDate  = s.getEndDate();

if ((fromDate.before(startDate) || fromDate.equals(startDate)) && 
    (toDate.after(endDate) || toDate.equals(endDate)){

   // do you magic here
}
```